# Create own widget for DropdownButtonFormField

Tags: flutter, dart

For call multiple input field use below code:

**_textInput(controller: txtEmail, label: 'Email',validate: _validateEmail)**

```
Widget _textInput({controller, label, validate}){
      return Container(
        child: TextField(
          controller: controller,
          obscureText: passmode,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              fillColor: Colors.transparent,
              filled: true,
              labelText: label,
              errorText: validate ? 'required!' : null,
              hintText: ''),
        ),
      );
    }
```

How create widget for DropdownButtonFormField

```
Widget _dropdown({value, name}){
  return Container(
    child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
      value: value,
      hint: Text(
        'Salutation',
      ),
      onChanged: (newValue) =>
          setState(() {
            name = newValue;
          }),
      validator: (value) =>
      value == null ? 'Required!' : null,
      items: ['MR.', 'MS.']
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    ),
  );
}
```

How use setState in widget?

[image]

Comment: can you explain a little more what errors you are getting?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh  I'm update question!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know is below example good solution but working.

```
class MyDrop extends StatefulWidget {
  late  String? value, name;
  MyDrop({Key? key, required this.value, required this.name}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyDropState createState() => _MyDropState();
}

class _MyDropState extends State<MyDrop> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
        value: widget.value,
        hint: Text(
          'Salutation',
        ),
        onChanged: (newValue) =>
            setState(() {
              widget.name = newValue;
            }),
        validator: (value) =>
        value == null ? 'Required!' : null,
        items: ['MR.', 'MS.']
            .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value,
            child: Text(value),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

call:

```
MyDrop(name: name1,value: selectedValue1,),
MyDrop(name: name2,value: selectedValue2,),
```